# Download CSV using Browser

Tags: python, request, export, export-to-csv

I have created an API using python and on the client side, I have data which I want to export in CSV. Python is exporting it directly but I want that when I hit the export button on the browser (created by client-side) then it should be exporting it, using browser's download feature

This is the code

```
data=pd.DataFrame(result,columns=col)
data.to_excel(name+'.xls',index=False,header=True)
```

This is directly exporting the data to csv but I want the same to be happening from browser's download feature

Comment: So what's your question? What have you tried? I don't see any code here

Comment: modified my post

Answer (score 1):

Add these headers to your API response headers in your python code, the browser will download the file as CSV.

```
"Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
"Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=file_name.csv"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding": "bytes"
```

The browser will understand this information and download the file and put response body in it.

Comment: how to modify the code to merge with requests bcoz by default it is converted to csv using pandas

Comment: where exactly you send your data to the client? you should do this at the end before sending data.

Comment: I am actually getting data in variable and I tried what u said but it is not working but giving me error-> InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found

Comment: how did you make an API?

Comment: I have created a python server and used handler class to handle all the HTTP requests. I am using the headers provided by you but still its directly downloading the file, without browser's prompt

Comment: I tried adding those headers in response header but still same issue